# How to do rolling weeks based on date?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm currently at a data analyst student job following an internship and I have do to reports based on the ticketing tool of the company, so, I'm using a pre-calculated table (the administrator have made pre-calculated tables based on his querys).

I have week table with all I need and I have to do a rolling 26 week report.

Because it is calculated that are historized and I don't have creation_date or end_date column.
I can't manage to do this can you help me with this ?

Actually, as a rolling query, if I have 18 weeks for 2021 I will need the 8 weeks last weeks of 2020.

I have this columns : Closed, Week, Month, Backlog... and I need it just for Closed.

I've tried this :

```
SELECT SUM(CLOSED), WEEK, MONTh, YEAR 
FROM E_GROUPE_INTERVENANT_SEMAINE_HISTORY 
WHERE MONTH >= Month(getdate())-6 
      AND YEAR <= YEAR(getdate())
```

EDIT : The weeks range values 1 trough 53 or 52 it depends on the year, the weeks are weeks of month, I've tried this

SELECT SUM(CLOSED), WEEK, MONTH, YEAR
FROM E_GROUPE_INTERVENANT_SEMAINE_HISTORY
WHERE
YEAR(DATEADD(WEEK, -26, GETDATE())) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
AND
YEAR = YEAR(GETDATE())
AND
MONTH <= Month(DATEADD(WEEK, -26, GETDATE()))
)
group by WEEK, MONTH, YEAR
order by WEEK, YEAR

But I'm only getting week for the current year the previous year doesn't show.
I wonder if it's even possible to have the last year because without the pre-calculated tables I could get the last year with my querys but they want me to use this table.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please add the full schema of your table along with sample data and expected results, edit your question and include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ugh - this would be so much easier with a DATE field. What is WEEK - week of year or week of month?

Comment: What is the range of values in WEEK? 1 through 53?  The values for MONTH are numbers ranging from 1 to 12 - correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what your week value is but this will get you close:

```
SELECT SUM(CLOSED), WEEK, MONTH, YEAR 
FROM E_GROUPE_INTERVENANT_SEMAINE_HISTORY 
WHERE   (--CURRENT YEAR WHEN YEAR IS NOT CROSSED
        YEAR(DATEADD(WEEK, -18, GETDATE())) = YEAR(GETDATE())
        AND
        YEAR = YEAR(GETDATE())
        AND
        MONTH >= Month(DATEADD(WEEK, -18, GETDATE()))
        )
    OR
        (  --LAST MONTHS OF LAST YEAR WHEN YEAR IS SPANNED
        MONTH >= Month(DATEADD(WEEK, -18, GETDATE()))
        AND 
        YEAR = YEAR(DATEADD(WEEK, -18, GETDATE()))
        )       
    OR
        (--ALL MONTHS FOR CURRENT YEAR WHEN YEAR IS CROSSED
        YEAR(DATEADD(WEEK, -18, GETDATE())) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
        AND
        YEAR = YEAR(GETDATE())
        AND
        MONTH <= Month(DATEADD(WEEK, -18, GETDATE()))
        )
```